# Trying to repaint stateless child class from stateful parent class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I will simplify what I'm trying to do. My app has two element on the HomePage(Stateful) class => one button and one custom class named BallsContainer(Stateless) which is a Container with a method named changeNumbers which calls LottoGame method changeNumber. BallsContainer's child is LottoGame(stateless). LottoGame is also a Container with int ballNumber = 0 property and changeNumber(){ballNumber = 10} method. LottoGame's child is named Ball(stateless) is a Stack with CircleAvatar and a Text(shows number) and a property final int ballNumber.
Now from HomePage button I write a code like this.

var ballsContainer = BallsContainer();// This is on class level
onPressed(){setState(){ballsContainer.changeNumbers();}}

In BallContainer class changeNumbers(){lottoGame.changeNumber();} // lottoGame is on class level defined

In LottoGame class changeNumber(){ballNumber = 10}

When I tap button methods are called but LottoGame class doesn't rebuild.I also tried with changing LottoGame to a StatefullWidget but it also didn't work.Shouldn't setState rebuild all its child widgets? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using flutter a little incorrectly, its trick is that if the widget has not changed, it is not redrawn. You do not need to store widgets in class fields, but call the widget constructor each time and pass the necessary arguments to it, as soon as you pass the changed arguments, the widgets that depend on them will be redrawn

Comment: Also check out classes such as ValueKey and ChangeNotifier and Bloc